# Find origin of event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a *huge* app which is a conglomeration many different repos and addons. Under a very specific condition my app is redirecting somewhere it shouldn't. I think this is a result of some event handler. Is there a way I can put break or spit out the stack to find what is firing this event? The app is using emberjs and this is the oldest stack frame I can get to:

```
  this._hashchangeHandler = function (event) {
    (0, _emberMetal.run)(function () {
      var path = _this.getURL();
      if ((0, _emberMetal.get)(_this, 'lastSetURL') === path) {
        return;
      }

      (0, _emberMetal.set)(_this, 'lastSetURL', null);

      callback(path);
    });
  };

  window.addEventListener('hashchange', this._hashchangeHandler);
```

but I want to figure out what/where the `hashchange` event is originating from.